# Gitlab API commits diff dont get all files

Tags: git, gitlab, diff

i imported my project from my personal server who runs gitea to gitlab. now i try to write a update function and use the gitlab api. i think it works good but i run the diff function to compare to files and by one commit it contains much files. 
i call this api function:

> https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/project:id/repository/commits/commit:id/diff?page=3

on page 1 and 2 it show me all files but after page 2 the api call me it gives no more diffs but i look in my prject commits in gitlab it show me very more files. i think its a api error but i hope anyone have another idea

Answer (score 1):

> in gitlab it show me very more files

Check the nature of the diff shown.
If:

- the diffs are eol (end of lines) related
- you have a configuration like `true` or `input` for `git config core.autocrlf`

that would explain the extra diffs.

Try again, but this time cloning your repo after typing first:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```